# Finding correlations between plant features?

Tags: visualization, correlation, data-analysis

I have a list of flowers, and each has a color and a fragrance intensity. Each data row has a color and intensity for one breed of flower, like this:

```
Mauve   intense 
Mauve   intense 
Mauve   intense 
Mauve   moderate
Mauve   moderate
Mauve   moderate 
Mauve   moderate 
Mauve   none
Mauve   slight
Mauve   slight
Mauve   slight
```

I'm having trouble finding a tool which will take this data and turn it into a correlation matrix. I'm somewhat new to this, so I'm not sure if this would even be the right term for this kind of visualization. Basically I want to show how likely different colors are to be strong in fragrance rather than moderate.

Any suggestions? I am somewhat facile in R and tableau.

Comment: First, you should transform your data to integers according to your color intensity. Ex: Slight = 1, Moderate = 2 and Intense = 3. For colors, you can use the RGB values (ex: (230, 200,58) for Mauve). Then, any correlation algorithm should work.

Comment: Note that the LAB color (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) might be more "human" friendly than RGB since the human eyes does not interpret color linearly. So if you want color that *looks* equal, use LAB. If you just want to represent the color as a vector RGB is fine

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was hoping to find correlation between categorical variables (likelihood that flower is orange AND intense aroma) but it seems that most definitions of correlation essentially take two continuous variables, put them in a scatter plot, and then apply a function that assigns a value to whether they tend to increase with each other. Is this accurate?